# Percona UDF - FUNCTION MURMUR_HASH does not exist

Tags: mysql, percona

We have a 5.5.28-29.3-log mysql master that has the percona UDFs installed including murmur_hash.

We installed mysql on new host but I can't seem to find where to get the UDFs from. This doc suggests that they should come build into mysql 5.5.8-20.0 (and above?):

http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/management/udf_percona_toolkit.html

> 5.5.8-20.0: Began distributing libfnv1a_udf, libfnv_udf, and libmurmur_udf.

But they're definitely not in /usr/lib/mysql/plugin:

```
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin$ ls lib*
libdaemon_example.so
```

On the master:

```
mysql> select murmur_hash('12345');
+----------------------+
| murmur_hash('12345') |
+----------------------+
| -8902960671973102832 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

On the slave:

```
mysql> select murmur_hash('adsf');
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION murmur_hash does not exist
```

I sense I'm missing something obvious.

```
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS"
```

Comment: I think it might be this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-server/+bug/1294216

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it was this bug i.e. that the UDFs just weren't distributed with the version of mysql we were using, i.e. 5.5.36-34.0-632.lucid-log:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-server/+bug/1294216

To fix, we just upgraded to the latest version.